# Disable Clutter (Top and Sidebar) on external Monitor

Tags: unity

I want to user my Ubuntu computer during a show. I will have 3 Outputs connected, 1 for my program list, 1 for preview and one for my live output.

I want to avoid that on the live output will be an overlay of the top and sidebar of ubuntu/unity. Is it possible to disable these on one monitor?

Comment: BTW.: I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the side bar (launcher) to only appear on the primary display, under *Displays* in *System Settings*. However, the top panel will appear on all screens. If you run something in full screen mode on the display where you wish to hide the top panel though, it will be hidden by the full screen window. Also, if you wish to avoid notifications popping up on the live output, it's best to arrange it to the left of the primary display, as notifications will pop up in the top right most corner.

Comment: The Problem is even if the application is a full screen window like vlc full screen playback or evince full screen pdf view, the bar is shown if the application is not in focus.